# why is "export default" not working in my node back end code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Does anybody know why I can do some es6 things like arrow functions in my node back-end code (without babel), but I can't do other es6 things like "export default"? (get an error " Unexpected token 'export'")

I'm using node 12.14 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can. Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`.

Check out the Node.js documentation for [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

The reason it took them so long to implement this is that...it's complicated. [Read more about the challenges here](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e).